# python - Password checker program, while loops not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a password validator/checker program as part of my computing assignment.It must have an uppercase and lowercase letter and be at least 8 characters long.
So far I have done this:

```
new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")

while new_password != new_password2:
    print("The passwords don't match up.")
    new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
    new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")

if new_password == new_password2:
    length = len(new_password)
    while int(length) < 8:
        print("Your password must be longer")
        new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
        new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")      
    letters = set(new_password)
    lower = any(letter.islower() for letter in letters)
    while new_password == new_password2:
        if not lower:
            print("Your password must contain a lowercase letter")
            new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
            new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")
    upper = any(letter.isupper() for letter in letters)
    while new_password == new_password2 :
        if not upper:
            print("Your password must contain an uppercase letter")
            new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
            new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")
```

The code runs, but for some reason, the while loops do not work as even if the condition is right,( eg. the password contains an uppercase letter), the option for the user to enter the password again is being displayed. Can someone take a look and tell me the problem here? Thanks

Comment: Note: the line `if new_password == new_password2:` is not required, as that line will only be run when they DO equal.

Comment: 1) `if new_password == new_password2:` at the beginning is useless as after the first loop these variables are 100% equal. So, remove that and thus save a level of indentation; 2) `int(length)` is useless as in `length = len(new_password)` `length` is an integer already;

Comment: 3) In the 3rd `while` loop: `while new_password == new_password2`: what if `new_password != new_password2`? You drop out of the loop and move on while you totally shouldn't; 4) The same thing in the last loop;

Comment: 5) You don't update neither `lower`, nor `upper` in the loops, so `not lower` and `not upper` are _constants_; So, your code is seriously broken, unfortunately. I suggest you drop that, sit down with a pen and a piece of paper and come up with an algorithm first. Make sure it works _in theory_ and then translate it into Python. Once you know _what you're doing_ it'll become so much easier to write code.

Comment: Check this output on **Python-idle** `print dir(__builtins__)`  Don't use the names in this list(The modules you import are also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to only have one while loop in which every requirement is checked. See the following code:

```
valid_password = False

while not valid_password: 
    new_password = input("Please enter your new password: ")
    new_password2 = input("Please enter your new password again: ")

    if new_password != new_password2:
        print("The passwords don't match up.")
        continue
    elif len(new_password) < 8:
        print("Your password must be longer")
        continue
    elif new_password.upper() == new_password or new_password.lower() == new_password:
        print("Your password must contain at least one lowercase and uppercase letter")
        continue
    else:
        print("Password Accepted!")
        valid_password = True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ForceBru I know, it's just force of habit to use that anywhere in a loop where that statement should restart the loop. Also, imho it looks nice and makes the code more readable

Answer (score 0):

```
a= int (input("Enter Passcode: "))
if a == 1974:
   print ("     Welcome!!    ")

else:
   print ("Wrong Passcode")
   print ("Run again")
```